# Distribution of coalition cost among coalition members (game theory) on the basis of contribution in coalition

Tags: game-theory

Does any one know or point out the method or technique used for the distribution of the coalition cost among the coalition members depending upon their contributions in the coalition. In other words, if a member of the coalition contributes more in the coalition as compared to others then the share of the coalition cost would be less as compared to others?

Comment: Look up the "Shapley value" or the "VCG mechanism".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this question and it's the base of any coalition.

*Shapley value* is the most famous(maybe I think). *Nocleolus value* is another solution.